# Find all natrual numbers that are $13$ times bigger than the sum of their digits.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

> Find all natural numbers that are $13$ times bigger than the sum of their digits.

---

I had a solution and just wanted to verify it. By solving the equation $$13(a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots a_n)=\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_n},$$ we can get $n=3$ and by putting the number $\overline{abc}$ in the equation, I got three answers.

Right? Thanks!

Comment: @kingW3 I've got the answers $195,117,156$.

Comment: You're right I've started counting from $13\cdot 10$, seems correct since trivially there are no solutions past $13\cdot 27$ (and $13\cdot 27$ is not a solution).

Comment: I got the same results. I don't know you approach, but my approach leads me to the equation $b+4c=29a$ with $a,b,c \in \{0, \dotsc, 9 \}$. Obviously this enforces $a=1$, and then you get precisely those three solutions.,

Comment: Since this is an Q&A site, you should post an answer to your own question (and of course provide some insights on how to arrive at $n=3$ etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An $n$-digit number is  $\ge 10^{n-1}$, but the sum of its digits $\le 9n$. This give us the inequality $10^{n-1}\le 13\cdot 9n=117n$, which easily leads to $n\le 3$. 
Then $13\cdot(a+b+c)=100a+10b+c$ leads to $87a=3b+12c$, or $29a=b+4c$.

- With $a=0$, we arrive at $b=c=0$.
- With $a=1$, we arrive at $b+4c=29$, hence $5\le c\le 7$, with each case leading to a valid solution
- With $a\ge 2$, $9+4\cdot 9\ge b+4c\ge 58$ leads to a contradiction

That's four solutions in total if we allow $0$ a a solution